# Is it possible to give a HTML submit button more than one color?

Tags: html, css

My client has asked me for a submit button with 2 words and 3 different text colors:

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT NEWSLETTER" />
```

SUBMIT = black
NEWS = black
LET = white
TER = black

I'm guessing CSS won't do this. Maybe Javascript?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: make a <button></button> and do the image background

Comment: Here is an example of using buttons and breaking the text into different spans: https://jsfiddle.net/bfev9x66/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a button and put a span in it

```
<button type="submit">SUBMIT NEWS<span style="color:white">LET</span>TER</button>
```

[image]

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lczmkmr1/

Answer (score 3):

It works with `button`, `span` and CSS.

```html
<button type="submit" style="background-color:#ff0000">
    <span style="color: #ffffff">Submit</span> 
    <span style="color: #000000">Newsletter</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with css, you just need to use a span:

```
<button>Submit News<span id="white">let</span>ter</button>
```

and the css:

```
#white{
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answers posted minutes before?

Comment: is is not! as I started typing there where no answers, by the moment I clicked submit I saw all the other ones

Comment: Thats true I have also start answer but when I have seen there are lots of answer Juan Fernandez Ridano. Good Answer.

Answer (score 2):

**First is**

```
<button type="submit">SUBMIT NEWS<span style="color:#fff;">LET</span>TER</button>
```

**Second is**

```
<button type="submit">SUBMIT NEWS<span class="white">LET</span>TER</button`>

.white{
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answers posted minutes before?

Comment: @SatejS when were i writing answer other one post same answer.

Comment: Good for using a class name instead of inline styles

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible u can use span inside button tag.

`<button>
 <span style="color:red;">Click</span>
 <span style="color:blue">Me</span>
</button>`

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{

width:800px;
background-image: url(http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:439px;
margin-left:35px;
display:block;
color:white;
border: none;

}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

This is just a very big button because the image is too big adjust the height and width according to your need